# How can I make the height of an "outer" smaller in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm making 2 cards in CSS and I want the 2nd one to lay below the 1st one. In order to locate the first card in the middle I created a "card-outer" div, but when I click "inspect element" I see that the height of the outer is more than 900px, and therefore, the 2nd card is +900px lower than the 1st card.

Do you guys have any idea of how can I fix this issue?

It looks like this, and I want only a 50px separation between both:
[image]

```css
.card-outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(16, 33, 72);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #031e23;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.card .img-card {
  background: url(parque.png);
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 60% 0%;
}

.card .content {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 150px 50px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-outer">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-card"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="titulo">
        <h3>Parque Metropolitano</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi consectetur, accusamus repellat architecto veritatis quis vel harum molestiae tempore ea illo ut sapiente magnam voluptate.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-container">
        <button>Sitio web</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide [mcve] please not just some css

Comment: I'm new using stackoverflow but i think this is what you meant. It's the same code for the second card.